How a consumer able to get all messages from a particular partition of a topic?
I was going the Kafka tutorials and lead to one confusion. A topic is distributed in multiple partitions. A producer message goes only into one partition not all partition of a topic. When a consumer subscribe topic it is  assigned to a particular partition and it reads from that.
If above is true then how consumer can read all messages send to a topic when a partition does not get all the messages?
Please rectify if my assumption is wrong.
Thanks

Consumers can be assigned multiple partitions of a topic. Especially, if there is only one consumer in the consumer group.
Only when there's multiple group members, will each instance process a subset of the topic. Together, they consume all messages, of all partitions.
Documentation / tutorials often intermix "consumer" with the overall reading process (all instances are reading the entire topic), and an individual one (a consumer joins a group, and is assigned partitions)

So if i understand correctly then the consumer group concept is key here. In a group it is responsibility of the group to consume all the messages together not by one consumer.
However, if there is a single consumer then it has to connect to all the partition to read all the messages. let me know if my understanding is correct?

Yes. The group coordinator assigns the partitions to consumers of the group when they subscribe
